# How to convert to data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ampl

I have a data file that is a result of ampl. the file looks like this

```
x [*,*]
:     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19 :=
1     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
24    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
26    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
27    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
28    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
29    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
30    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
31    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
32    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
33    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
34    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
35    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
37    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
38    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
39    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
40    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
41    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
43    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
44    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
45    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
46    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
47    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
48    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
49    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
50    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
51    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
52    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
53    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
54    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
55    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
57    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
59    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
60    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
61    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
63    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
64    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
65    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
66    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
67    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
68    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
69    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
70    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
71    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
72    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
73    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
74    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
75    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
76    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
77    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
78    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
79    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
80    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
81    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
82    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
83    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
84    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
85    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
86    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
87    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
88    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
89    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
90    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
91    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
92    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
93    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
94    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
95    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
96    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
97    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
98    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
99    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
101   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
102   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
103   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
104   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
105   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

:    20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38 :=
1     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
24    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
26    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
27    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
28    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
29    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
30    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
31    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
32    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
33    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
34    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
35    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
37    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
38    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
39    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
40    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
41    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
43    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
44    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
45    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
46    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
47    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
48    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
49    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
50    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
51    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
52    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
53    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
54    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
55    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
57    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
59    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
60    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
61    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
63    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
64    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
65    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
66    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
67    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
68    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
69    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
70    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
71    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
72    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
73    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
74    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
75    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
76    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
77    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
78    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
79    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
80    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
81    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
82    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
83    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
84    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
85    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
86    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
87    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
88    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
89    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
90    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
91    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
92    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
93    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
94    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
95    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
96    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
97    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
98    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
99    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
101   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
102   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
103   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
104   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
105   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0

:    39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57 :=
1     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
22    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
24    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
26    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
27    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
28    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
29    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
30    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
31    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
32    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
33    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
34    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
35    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
37    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
38    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
39    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
40    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
41    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
43    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
44    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
45    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
46    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
47    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
48    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
49    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
50    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
51    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
52    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
53    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
54    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
55    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
57    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
58    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
59    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
60    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
61    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
62    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
63    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
64    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
65    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
66    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
67    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
68    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
69    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
70    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
71    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
72    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
73    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
74    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
75    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
76    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
77    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
78    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
79    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
80    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
81    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
82    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
83    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
84    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
85    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
86    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
87    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
88    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
89    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
90    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
91    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
92    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
93    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
94    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
95    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
96    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
97    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
98    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
99    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
100   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
101   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
102   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
103   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
104   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
105   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
;
```

Its essentially a 105 X 56 matrix. How do I convert it into a data frame in python?

I want to be able to use the file dynamically. Currently I am converting the file from txt to csv and formatting it as I need. Can someone give me some ideas?

Comment: Use `pandas.DataFrame()`

Comment: I did, but there's text and the result is split over multiple lines. The first 19 columns then the next 19 and finally the rest

Answer (score 1):

One workaround could go as follows: read the file, split it into blocks (in this case separated by `\n\n`) and parse each block with `StringIO` + `pd.read_csv`. The solution below discards the column names, but as those are easily recoverable.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('temp.txt') as f:
    # exact copy of your input data
    f.readline()
    # drop the first line
    blocks = f.read().split('\n\n')
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(StringIO(block), sep=r' +', header=None, skiprows=1, skipfooter=1, index_col=0)
        for i, block in enumerate(blocks)), axis=1)
    df.columns = [i for i in range(1, len(df.columns)+1)]
    df.set_index(df.index.values + 1, inplace=True)
```